# Dropdown click open on mobile, hover on desktop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, responsive-design

I am trying to have navbar dropdowns open on hover on desktop, and on-click on mobile. I've looked at several similar questions, but thought my approach would be easier to read and in practice, work without a hitch.

This code alone allows both desktop and mobile dropdowns to open with a click:

```js
$('.anchor').click(function() { 
  $(this).siblings('.navigation__dropdown').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

I've made the following jQuery function, which is tested and works (per with `.css` and `.removeClass`, `console.log`, etc). But here, in place, I've added a `.click` to open dropdowns on mobile, and a `.hover` to open dropdowns on desktop:

```js
(function ($) {
  $(function () {
    var mq = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 800px)');
    mq.addEventListener('change', function () {
      if (mq.matches) {
        $('.anchor').click(function() {
        $(this).siblings('.navigation__dropdown').slideToggle('slow');
      } else {
        $('.anchor').hover(function() {
        $(this).siblings('.navigation__dropdown').slideToggle('slow');
    });
  }
});
```

However, after I load the website at desktop width, the following happens:

1. Desktop dropdowns do not open at all (undesired outcome). Using the "document ready" shorthand, I thought it would detect the viewport width when the page loaded?
2. I resize to mobile, and clicks open dropdowns (desired outcome).
3. I resize back to desktop, and hover works on dropdowns (desired outcome).
4. I resize to mobile again, and now dropdowns open on hover (undesired outcome). From this point, both views are locked in hover only.

Regardless of when `.hover()` is called (e.g. whether in an `if` or `else`, the result always gets stuck on hover animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using a combination of `.on()` and `.hover()` vs `.click()` and `hover.()`.

```js
$('.anchor').on('click', function (e) {
        if (mq.matches) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).next($('.navigation__dropdown')).slideToggle('fast');

          $('.navigation__dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide('fast');
          e.stopPropagation();
        }
      })
      $('.anchor').hover(function (e) {
        if (!mq.matches) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).next($('.navigation__dropdown')).slideToggle('fast');

          $('.navigation__dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide('fast');
          e.stopPropagation();
        }
      })
```